# Aurelia validate one datetime is greater than the other

Tags: validation, datetime, aurelia, custom-element

I have two date/times that come from a db, however these are split into four (two dates and two times) on the view, both the date and time are custom elements. See below.

[image]

My issue is my start date/time cannot be greater than my end date/time. I know how to do this in c#:

- Check whether date string contains a default time 00:00:00, if so remove.
- Parse date/time strings in a new datetime
- Repeat for second date/time
- Validate whether from < to (`return from < to`)

But I don't know how to do this in Aurelia without doing a API call. I have noted `isLessThan`, however I would need to parse my strings into a datetime before I can do that.

```
      bind(){
            return this.dataContext.getContent(this.id)
                .then(baseContent => {
                    this.baseContent = baseContent;
                     this.validator = this.validation.on(this)                                         
    .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate').isNotEmpty()
                            .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromTime').isNotEmpty()
                            .ensure('baseContent.ValidToDate').isNotEmpty()
                            .ensure('baseContent.ValidToTime').isNotEmpty()
.ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate / baseContent.ValidFromTime').isLessThan('baseContent.ValidToDate / baseContent.ValidToTime')
;
                }); }
```

I know the above doesn't work, I am new to Aurelia and still finding my feet with it.

**UPDATE**

I've tried the following but received a:

> Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: path.split is not a function

I think the issue is it doesn't know what to assign the error message to but I could be wrong.

```
.ensure(this.datetimeformat.format(baseContent.ValidFromDate, baseContent.ValidFromTime)).isLessThan(this.datetimeformat.format(baseContent.ValidToDate, baseContent.ValidFromTime));

import moment from 'moment';

export class DateTimeFormat {
    format(date, time) {

        if (date.indexOf("T") > -1) {
            date = date.split('T')[0];
        }

        return moment(date + 'T' + time, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');
    }
}
```

I noticed one of the answers used a computedFrom however as I need to first change these into DateTime, and parse back I don't know what I am meant to provide where.

**UPDATE**

```
.ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate', (config) => { config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) }).isNotEmpty().passes(() => {
                        return this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime) < this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidToDate, this.baseContent.ValidToTime);
                    })
```

I think I am getting closer, but still not working :-(

I have also tried

```
.ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate', (config) => { config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) }).if(() => {
                        return this.baseContent.ValidFromDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidFromTime !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToTime !== null})
                        .passes( () => {return this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime) < this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidToDate, this.baseContent.ValidToTime)})
                    .endIf().isNotEmpty()
```

No errors with developer tools.

```
function validateFromDateTimeIsBeforeToDateTime(dateFrom, timeFrom, dateTo, timeTo) {
        debugger;
        if (dateFrom !== null && dateFrom !== undefined &&
        timeFrom !== null && timeFrom !== undefined &&
        dateTo !== null && dateTo !== undefined &&
        timeTo !== null && timeTo !== undefined) {

            return this.datetimeformat.format(dateFrom, timeFrom) < this.datetimeformat.format(dateTo, timeTo);
    } 
    else {
        return true;
    }
}

                    .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate').isNotEmpty().passes(validateFromDateTimeIsBeforeToDateTime(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime, this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime))
                    .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromTime').isNotEmpty()
                    .ensure('baseContent.ValidToDate').isNotEmpty().passes(validateFromDateTimeIsBeforeToDateTime(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime, this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime))
                    .ensure('baseContent.ValidToTime').isNotEmpty()
```

This however throws an "Unhandled promise rejection TypeError: Unable to get property 'datetimeformat' of undefined or null reference"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a-lot of investigation, fixing bugs here and there, I noted the outstanding issue was from my formatting class, it wasn't creating the date/time (using moment.js) correctly (after the user has selected from the calendar), meaning it returned 'invalid date' which you cannot compare on :-|

This will work:

```
this.validator = this.validation.on(this)
                    .ensure('baseContent.ValidFromDate', (config) => { config.computedFrom(['baseContent.ValidFromDate', 'baseContent.ValidFromTime', 'baseContent.ValidToDate', 'baseContent.ValidToTime']) })
                        .if(() => {
                            return this.baseContent.ValidFromDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidFromTime !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToDate !== null && this.baseContent.ValidToTime !== null })
                            .passes( () => { return this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidFromDate, this.baseContent.ValidFromTime) < this.datetimeformat.format(this.baseContent.ValidToDate, this.baseContent.ValidToTime) })
                            .withMessage('< Valid To')
                        .endIf()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the ubiquitous moment.js library in this case:

`jspm install moment`

Then use it like this for example:

```
import moment from 'moment';

export class MyViewModel {
  date1 = "2016-02-29";
  time1 = "09:00:00";
  date2 = "2016-03-01";
  time2 = "13:00:00";

  myMethod() {
    let isValid = moment(`${this.date1 this.time1`).isBefore(moment(`${this.date2 this.time2`));
    alert(isValid);
  }
}
```

Comment: If I create this within the the parent, how to I call this? i.e. this.validator = this.validation.on(this).ensure(myMethod)? Sorry I am pretty new to this, its taking me a while to get my head round it.

Answer (score -1):

```
.ensure('toDate', (config) => {config.computedFrom(['fromDate'])})
   .isGreaterThan( () => {return this.fromDate}, 'the entered Date');
```

Comment: How would I concat the date and time?